# I tried this proxy checker, it shows urrlib2 is not defined on execution and get stuck for a while?

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, urllib2

It says urllib2 is not defined

> Nameerror : Global name 'urllib2' is not defined

I am using Python 2.7, can anyone help me out to fix this one? It's not my code tho but still needs some help regarding it.

And please if you guys can make some edit to make it use less cpu usage and good 
execution time?

I am just a beginner in sending http request

```
from grab import Grab, GrabError
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import requests
from urllib2 import urlopen



""" A multithreaded proxy checker

Given a file containing proxies, per line, in the form of ip:port, will attempt
to establish a connection through each proxy to a provided URL. Duration of
connection attempts is governed by a passed in timeout value. Additionally,
spins off a number of daemon threads to speed up processing using a passed in
threads parameter. Proxies that passed the test are written out to a file
called results.txt

Usage:

    goodproxy.py [-h] -file FILE -url URL [-timeout TIMEOUT] [-threads THREADS]

Parameters:

    -file    -- filename containing a list of ip:port per line
    -url     -- URL to test connections against
    -timeout -- attempt time before marking that proxy as bad (default 1.0)
    -threads -- number of threads to spin off (default 16)

Functions:

    get_proxy_list_size  -- returns the current size of the proxy holdingQueue
    test_proxy            -- does the actual connecting to the URL via a proxy
    main                 -- creates daemon threads, write results to a file

"""
import argparse
import queue
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time



def get_proxy_list_size(proxy_list):
    """ Return the current Queue size holding a list of proxy ip:ports """

    return proxy_list.qsize()


def test_proxy(url, url_timeout, proxy_list, lock, good_proxies, bad_proxies):
    """ Attempt to establish a connection to a passed in URL through a proxy.

    This function is used in a daemon thread and will loop continuously while
    waiting for available proxies in the proxy_list. Once proxy_list contains
    a proxy, this function will extract that proxy. This action automatically
    lock the queue until this thread is done with it. Builds a urllib.request
    opener and configures it with the proxy. Attempts to open the URL and if
    successsful then saves the good proxy into the good_proxies list. If an
    exception is thrown, writes the bad proxy to a bodproxies list. The call
    to task_done() at the end unlocks the queue for further processing.

    """

    while True:

        # take an item from the proxy list queue; get() auto locks the
        # queue for use by this thread
        proxy_ip = proxy_list.get()

        # configure urllib.request to use proxy
        proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy_ip})
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

        # some sites block frequent querying from generic headers
        request = urllib.request.Request(
            url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Proxy Tester'})

        try:
            # attempt to establish a connection
            urllib.request.urlopen(request, timeout=float(url_timeout))

            # if all went well save the good proxy to the list
            with lock:
                good_proxies.append(proxy_ip)

        except (urllib.request.URLError,
                urllib.request.HTTPError,
                socket.error):

            # handle any error related to connectivity (timeouts, refused
            # connections, HTTPError, URLError, etc)
            with lock:
                bad_proxies.append(proxy_ip)

        finally:
            proxy_list.task_done()  # release the queue


def main(argv):
    """ Main Function

    Uses argparse to process input parameters. File and URL are required while
    the timeout and thread values are optional. Uses threading to create a
    number of daemon threads each of which monitors a Queue for available
    proxies to test. Once the Queue begins populating, the waiting daemon
    threads will start picking up the proxies and testing them. Successful
    results are written out to a results.txt file.

    """

    proxy_list = queue.Queue()  # Hold a list of proxy ip:ports
    lock = threading.Lock()  # locks good_proxies, bad_proxies lists
    good_proxies = []  # proxies that passed connectivity tests
    bad_proxies = []  # proxies that failed connectivity tests

    # Process input parameters
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Proxy Checker')

    parser.add_argument(
        '-file', help='a text file with a list of proxy:port per line',
        required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-url', help='URL for connection attempts', required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-timeout',
        type=float, help='timeout in seconds (defaults to 1', default=1)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-threads', type=int, help='number of threads (defaults to 16)',
        default=16)

    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    # setup daemons ^._.^
    for _ in range(args.threads):
        worker = threading.Thread(
            target=test_proxy,
            args=(
                args.url,
                args.timeout,
                proxy_list,
                lock,
                good_proxies,
                bad_proxies))
        worker.setDaemon(True)
        worker.start()

    start = time.time()

    # load a list of proxies from the proxy file
    with open(args.file) as proxyfile:
        for line in proxyfile:
            proxy_list.put(line.strip())

    # block main thread until the proxy list queue becomes empty
    proxy_list.join()

    # save results to file
    with open("result.txt", 'w') as result_file:
        result_file.write('\n'.join(good_proxies))

    # some metrics
    print("Runtime: {0:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Please try to post a minimal example of your code. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html for urllib2 documentation and try go get a minimal example running. Debugging third-party code is hard.